# how to export the excelsheet to an existing angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG5BT.png)
this is the error I'm getting after using the command: npm install xlsx --save
I would like to export the excel sheet i have on my local disk and the expected output should be in the form of a table
error message:

```
 npm install exceljs
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @nebular/theme@9.1.0-rc.8
npm ERR! Found: @angular/cdk@12.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"12.1.0" from the root project


npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/cdk@"^13.0.0" from @nebular/theme@9.1.0-rc.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@nebular/theme
npm ERR!   peer @nebular/theme@"9.1.0-rc.8" from @nebular/auth@9.1.0-rc.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nebular/auth
npm ERR!     @nebular/auth@"9.1.0-rc.8" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @nebular/theme@"9.1.0-rc.8" from @nebular/eva-icons@9.1.0-rc.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nebular/eva-icons
npm ERR!     @nebular/eva-icons@"9.1.0-rc.8" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (the root project)
```

can someone help me install this and export the Excel sheet to the existing project?
project link: https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin

Comment: please edit your question to include the error message with text instead of an images.

Comment: What version of nodejs are you running? You can check by running `node -v` in your terminal. I'm pretty sure you're running an incompatible version.

Comment: @akseli Im using v16.16.0

Comment: Try running it with node v14. If you haven't yet, I find it useful to install `nvm` on all dev machines in order to easily switch between node versions.

Comment: Also, I personally use `xlsx` for exporting from angular projects to Excel. `npm install --save xlsx`